# Submit a form using button type="button" instead of submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, submit, parsley.js

Currently I have an ASP.net page that has one form wrapper that incases the entire page. Within that page I have two forms with two respective submit buttons. I'm using parsley.js to validate, and with the help of @RickS, I have got the submit buttons validating their respective forms. 
However, in order to do that I've had to use button type="button" to do so but when I do that the form no longer submits. I'm sure there's a very obvious solution but it's not smacking me in the face. Does anyone out there have a quick fix solution?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/20/) to show what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<form method='post' id='form'>
<div>
    <input type='text' id='firstname' name='firstname' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <input type='text' id='lastname' name='lastname' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <input type='text' id='phone' name='phone' data-parsley-group="first" required />
    <button type="button" id="submit-form">Submit</button>
</div>

<div>
    <input type='text' id='thisisrequired' name='thisisrequired' data-parsley-group="second" required />
    <button type="button" id="submit-form2">Submit 2</button>
</div>
```

```
$('#form').parsley();
$("#submit-form").on('click', function () {
$('#form').parsley().validate("first");
if ($('#form').parsley().isValid()) {
    console.log('valid');
} else {
    console.log('not valid');
}
$("#submit-form2").on('click', function () {
$('#form').parsley().validate("second");
if ($('#form').parsley().isValid()) {
    console.log('valid');
} else {
    console.log('not valid');
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Learner, do you know why it's not submiting? I see if I fill out both forms it then sends but not if I just fill out one.

Comment: Yeah and therein lies my problem, @Learner . ASP.net only allows one form tag. If I could use multiple forms then I'd be fine but not so. Do you have any other ideas? Really appreciate your help.

Comment: and how about this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2005/10/19/482778.aspx

Comment: Thanks @Learner that's an interesting article but seems a little hacky. Is there someway that I could alter the if statement to say when form1 has passed parsley validation then submit? Because at the moment the isValid is requiring both forms to be filled out in order to be submitted.

Comment: Yeah I saw your second example @Learner but I can only have one form on the entire page. If I could have two forms then this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/26/

Comment: You're a legend @Learner thanks so much!

Comment: Hi @Learner, I've got another tricky problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31290192/using-an-input-submit-field-to-submit-instead-of-button-with-parsley-js that I'm struggling with that's related to this problem. Any chance you could take a look at it? I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/29/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had help from @Learner with this one who made this fiddle - jsfiddle.net/ukgvam9k/26

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$('#submit-form2').click(function(){
    $('#form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
$('#submit-form2').click(function () {
    $('#form').submit();
});
```